# Editing my answer on SO but text is being truncated by the editor

Tags: bug, design

I went to edit one of my answers on Stack Overflow and am getting a reproduceable issue with the text editor truncating the text in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41278053/2110294).

Basically all I am doing to reproduce this is adding two periods, so I tried to use the text **S.O.** instead of **SO** but it truncates that line and leaves only **O.** out of the whole sentence.

Here are two screenshots, one is before editing:

[image: before edit]

And after editing:

[image]

Here is the answer I posted:

```
Hello and welcome to SO

(I cheated and used Google but amended the info according to your question.)

Source : [How To Set Up Mod_Rewrite ][1]

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^thread/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ threads/index?threadName=$1 [NC]

  [1]: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite
```

Answer (score 6):

See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/307988)

As stated in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/307988), some salutations like that are automatically removed, which I'm guessing is what happened since it was removed up to the first period.

I'm not sure why it was only removed after adding the punctuation but regardless, it should be removed.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks. But it does indeed have an odd way of doing so :s